# How to get device uid based on host name in Zenoss API

Tags: zenoss

I am new to Zenoss. I would like to know if there is any way to get the UID based on the device name. For example, in vCenter i have a VM with name 'MyTestVM' and i can see that in Zenoss Infrastructure section. I am developing a portal to show the monitoring graphs of CPU and Memory from zenoss. In order to do that i need to pass the UID to one of its API and i dont know how to get that UID of any device (VM specifically).

Any help here would be really helpful.

Regards,
Kiran

PS: Please help me out if there is any confusion in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, depending on what you need to.

## The quick and ugly way, is to pull the UID, or UUID from your browser.

1. navigate to the device details page under infrastructure/devices/...
2. the UID should appear in your address bar.
   if the URL is "https://zenoss5.zenoss-host-name/zport/dmd/Devices/Server/Linux/devices/x.x.x.x/devicedetail#deviceDetailNav:device_overview"
   then your UID is "/zport/dmd/Devices/Server/Linux/devices/x.x.x.x"

you can also find the UUID by inspecting the page source and searching for "uuid"

## The fun and more automatable way, is to use zendmd to look it up.

see the documentation here: [support.zenoss.com: zendmd intro](https://support.zenoss.com/hc/en-us/articles/202946755-An-Introduction-to-zendmd)

1. attach to your zope container, and su to the zenoss user.
2. run `zendmd`
3. Find the device using its name:

   `In [1]: find('MyTestVM')
   Out[1]: <Device at /zport/dmd/Devices/Server/Linux/devices/x.x.x.x>
   In [2]: mydevice = find('MyTestVM')
   Out[3]: '3c5a857a-7d9f-4df9-bff9-2fcb9a07acbc'`
4. get the details you need from your dmd device:

   - UUID:

   `In [3]: mydevice.getUUID()
   Out[3]: '3c5a857a-7d9f-4df9-bff9-2fcb9a07acbc'`

   - ID:

   `In [4]: mydevice.getId()
   OUT[4]: 'x.x.x.x'`

## The best way, is probably to use the JSON API.

there is a [json api guide](http://wiki.zenoss.org/Working_with_the_JSON_API), and [full API documentation](https://www.zenoss.com/services-support/documentation/zenoss-json-api)